# How to go over each letter of a word and change it in bash

Tags: bash

My code looks like this

```
foo=`cat $words`
for (( i=0; i<${#foo}; i++ )); do
    new=${foo:$i:1}
    while IFS=read -r line 
    do
        if [[ $new=="#" ]]
        then 
            echo "<rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />"
        elif [[ $new==[A-Z] ]]
        then
            echo "<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />"
        fi
    done < "$new"
done
```

I get an error message containing the following

```
crossword: line 21: F: No such file or directory
2       crossword: line 21: G: No such file or directory
3       crossword: line 21: #: No such file or directory
4       crossword: line 21: 
5       : No such file or directory
6       crossword: line 21: Z: No such file or directory
7       crossword: line 21: #: No such file or directory
8       crossword: line 21: E: No such file or directory
9       crossword: line 21:
```

My desired output should have looked like this

```
 <rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
 <rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
 <rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />

 <rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
 <rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />
 <rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
```

Because the content of the file is

```
FG#
Z#E
```

Where # will be replaced by black and the letters with white

Comment: It's better to use sed or awk for actual text processing; bash is a decent shell, but doing text manipulation with a shell is not ideal.

Comment: You need spaces around `==` in the conditions.

Comment: What is **it** in the statement `I get an error message that it is not a directory`? Which line of code is associated with that error message? [edit] your question to show the exact error message along with whatever command you executed to produce it.

Comment: What are you intending with `done < "$new"`? `<` needs to be followed by a filename, but `$new` just contains one character from the file. And you do `read -r line`, but never use `$line` for anything. There seems to be no need for the `while` loop at all, the `for` loop should be enough.

Comment: If you do need the `while` loop, there should be a space between `IFS=` and `read`. And you need single quotes around the argument to `echo`, otherwise the quotes inside the tag will match the delimiter quotes.

Comment: First thing you need to do is paste this script into shellcheck.net.

Comment: You're showing us error messages claiming to come from line 21 of a script that's 14 lines long. Please post a minimal, complete script that demonstrates your problem and the error messages from THAT script, not from some other script.

Comment: The error messages are from `< "$new"` as I explained above. You're trying to use each character in the file as the name of an input file to read from. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Where are the incrementing numbers before each error message coming from? Does the script have `echo $i` that you didn't show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entire thing can be done with a single `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's|#|<rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />\n|g' -e 's|[A-Z]|<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />\n|g' "$words"
```

Comment: And what if I want to add 20 to x every time so that it goes like 20 for line one and 40 for line two etc

Comment: Then you need to use a scripting language with arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

We'd need more information to be able to debug whatever problem you're having but here's how to really do what you appear to be trying to do using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        lgth = length($0)
        for ( i=1; i<=lgth; i++ ) {
            char = substr($0,i,1)
            fill = (char == "#" ? "black" : "white")
            printf "<rect x=\"20\" y=\"20\" fill=\"%s\" />\n", fill
        }
        print ""
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />

<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
```

or maybe:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        lgth = length($0)
        for ( i=1; i<=lgth; i++ ) {
            char = substr($0,i,1)
            fill = ""
            if ( char == "#" ) {
                fill = "black"
            }
            else if ( char ~ /[A-Z]/ ) {
                fill = "white"
            }
            if ( fill != "" ) {
                printf "<rect x=\"20\" y=\"20\" fill=\"%s\" />\n", fill
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

,p>

```
$ ./tst.sh file
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />

<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="black" />
<rect x="20" y="20" fill="white" />
```